# Adding data to a silverlight HTTP POST Async

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, http-post

I'm trying to send some data using a simple HTTP POST in Silverlight 3.0 but for some reason I can't seem to find a good example on how to do this.

So far this works, but how do I send some data along w/ the request?

```
Public Sub SubmitMessage()
    request = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(New System.Uri("http://localhost:27856/Home.aspx/PostUpdate/"))
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim result As IAsyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf UpdateDone), Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateDone(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.EndGetResponse(ar)

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim valid As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `BeginGetRequestStream` method before getting the response (note VB.NET is not my main language).

```
Public Sub SubmitMessage()
    request = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(New System.Uri("http://localhost:27856/Home.aspx/PostUpdate/"))
    request.Method = "POST"

    request.BeginGetRequestStream(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf SendData), Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub SendData(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim stream as Stream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)
    '' # Pump your data as bytes into the stream.
    stream.Close()
    request.BeingGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf UpdateDone), Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateDone(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.EndGetResponse(ar)

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim valid As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Sub
```

It would seem from your answer that the are posting HTML form data.  Here is the correct way to create the entity body (C# sorry):-

```
    public static string GetUrlEncodedData(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var kvp in data)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append("&");
            sb.Append(kvp.Key);
            sb.Append("=");
            sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Note in particular the use of `Uri.EscapeDataString`, this the correct way to encode data values for this Content-Type.  It assumes that the server is expecting UTF-8 character encoding.

When converting the result of this to a byte array ready for posting you need only use ASCII encoding since the returned string will only ever contain characters within the ASCII range.

Comment: Directly after the request.BeginGetResponse(... the http POST is done and it jumps to the url mentioned w/out the stream attached.  Any way to attach this stream before this call in the first method above?

Comment: Looks like a small typo in your answer but it got me moving in the right direction!  I posted the final solution to clear up any confusion around this! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Oops, yes I quote the correct method but failed to actually tweak the code with it, done now.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution that worked is shown below.  Thanks to @[AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17516/anthonywjones) for his quick answer that got me moving in the right direction!

```
Public Sub SubmitMessage()
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(New System.Uri("http://localhost:27856/Home.aspx/PostUpdate/"))
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    request.BeginGetRequestStream(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf SendStatusUpdate), request)
End Sub

Public Sub SendStatusUpdate(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)

    Dim stream As Stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)

    Dim data As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = data.GetBytes("status=test")

    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    stream.Close()
    stream.Dispose()

    request.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf StatusUpdateCompleted), request)
End Sub

Public Sub StatusUpdateCompleted(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.EndGetResponse(ar)

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim valid As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: The default encoding for UploadStringAsync is UTF-8, have you tried using that?  Besides for true HTML form emulation this form of encoding is incorrect.  Is there are reason your not posting something like a XML or JSON?